# Text from textbox disapreared inside gridview which came from radiobutton list through Radiobuttonlist1.SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, gridview, textbox, radiobuttonlist

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listControl = (ListControl)sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow)listControl.NamingContainer;
    var value = listControl.SelectedValue;
    var items = listControl.SelectedItem;
    GridView2.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(value) - 1].Cells[3].Text = items;

 }
```

This is the code which I have written.. 
Please assist me on this. 
Please let me know for any concern/question.

Comment: Radiobuttonlist gave the list of model and I need to same the selected model in saperate row of gridview.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This text will only appear after the RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged event is fired. By the time you have any postback this text will disappear since this event will not be raised in the control load event. To make sure that the text will appear always during user actions. you can do the following.

```
private class SelectedItem
{
    public string Items { get; set; }
    public string Items { get; set; }

}
```

in the RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listControl = (ListControl)sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow)listControl.NamingContainer;
    var value = listControl.SelectedValue;
    var items = listControl.SelectedItem;
    var selectedItem =new SelectedItem();
    selectedItem.Items = items;
    selectedItem.Value= value;
    // Save the selected item in the session
    Sessions["SelectedItem"] = selectedItem;

 }
```

then in the page load event you can do the following :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // check is sessiosn is not null or empty

            if(Session["SelectedItem"]!= null)
            {
                var selectedItem = new SelectedItem();
                selectedItem = (SelectedItem)Session["SelectedItem"];
                GridView2.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(selectedItem.Value) - 1].Cells[3].Text = selectedItem.Items;


            }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.